# Search for estimates

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let's say I have an equation of the form $\Delta A = J$ where $J=u\nabla u + A|u|^2$. Then I could simply infer from Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev and Hölder that
$$\|A\|_6 \leq \|J\|_{6/5} \leq \|u\|_3\|\nabla u\|_2 +\|A\|_6 \|u\|_3^2$$
and then from Sobolev
$$\cdots \leq \|u\|_{H^1}^2 + \|A\|_6 \|u\|_{H^1}^2$$
Can I somehow infer from that that $\|A\|_6$ is controlled by some norm of $u$?